# The area enclosed by the locus of point C

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, triangles, conic-sections, locus

Triangle ABC is such that AB = 4, BC = 2, and AC = 3. If vertex A is confined to the x-axis and vertex B is confined to the y-axis, what is the area of the region enclosed by the locus of all points point C could possibly be?

Comment: There are four possible locations for C with four locus - rae you interested in the combined area of the intersections?

Comment: Yes, but are you sure there are four loci?

Comment: Choose A and B and you get two Cs. When you draw A moves from -4 to 4 B can move from 0 to 3 or -3

Comment: But how do you know that in moving points A and B in those distinct ways, you've generated four distinct loci?

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @MichaelMcGruder - where did you find this question?

Comment: I created it myself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Special Note**

Just found out that this is also known as **Van Schooten's Locus Problem**. Some good references [here](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/EllipseByVanSchooten.shtml), [here](http://www2.washjeff.edu/users/mwoltermann/Dorrie/47.pdf) and [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/10.4169/000298910x476068.pdf?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents). The second references contains a neat solution using a purely geometrical approach.

> **Additional Note VI (based on Van Schooten's solution)**

[image]

Refer to diagram above.
See Desmos implementation [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dhim8triao).

Let $L,M,N$ be the lengths of $AB, AC, BC$ respectively.
Let $Z$ be the midpoint of $AB$.
Note that $ZO=ZA=ZB$.
Let $ZO=ZA=ZB=R(=L/2)$.

Draw a circle centred passing through $A,B,O$. This circle has $Z$ as its centre.
Let $P$ be the point where the line $CZ$ extended meets the circle.
Let $Q$ be the point where the line $ZC$ extended meets the circle.
Hence $ZP=ZQ=R$.

Since the arc $AQ$ is fixed, $\angle AOQ=\angle ABQ $ (fixed). Hence the locus of $Q$ is a straight line $OQ$.
Since the arc $AP$ is fixed, $\angle AOP=\angle ABP $ (fixed). Hence the locus of $Q$ is a straight line $OP$.
And since $PQ$ is a diameter of the circle, $\angle POQ$ is a right angle, i.e. $OP,OQ$ are perpendicular.

Hence the $C$ can be viewed as a point on $PQ$, with $P,Q$ constrained to move along perpendicular lines $OP, OQ$.
**Hence $PCQ$ is a [Trammel of Archimedes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trammel_of_Archimedes)**.
**Therefore, the locus of $C$ is an ellipse with semi-major/minor axes $CP, CQ$.**

Let $w=CZ$. Hence semi-major/minor axes are $$r^*_1=CP=R+w\\r^*_2=CQ=R-w$$ 
Area enclosed by the locus of $C$ (i.e. the ellipse) is 
$$\pi \ r^*_1 r^*_2 = \pi (R^2-w^2)\tag{1}$$

Applying the cosine rule on triangles $ZAC, ZBC$:
$$\begin{align}
w^2&=M^2+R^2-2MR\cos\alpha\\
w^2&=N^2+R^2-2NR\;\cos\beta\\
\text{Adding:}\hspace{3cm}\\
2w^2&=M^2+N^2-2R(\underbrace{M\cos\alpha+N\cos\beta}_{=L=2R})\\
&=M^2+N^2-2R^2\\
w^2&=\frac {M^2+N^2}2-R^2\\
&=\frac {M^2+N^2}2-\frac {L^2}4\\
\therefore
R^2-w^2&=\frac {L^2}2-\left(\frac {M^2+N^2}2-\frac {L^2}4\right)\\
&=\frac {L^2-M^2-N^2}2
\end{align}$$
From $(1)$, 
 area enclosed by the locus of $C$ (i.e. the ellipse) is 
$$\pi \ r^*_1 r^*_2 = \pi (R^2-w^2)=\color{red}{\pi \left(\frac{L^2-M^2-N^2}2\right)}$$

---

---

> **Preamble from Original Answer**

Interesting problem (+1).

Assuming $A,B$ are confined to the positive $x,y$ axes respectively, this gives two possible positions for $C$, labelled $C, C'$, where $ACBC'$ forms a kite with centre $P$, which divides $AB$ into $p, q$, where $p+q=4$, and semi-wingspan $h$.

[image]

Define $\alpha=\angle CAB,\;\; \beta=\angle CBA,\;\; \theta=\angle BAO$.

Using geometry, it can be deduced that, using parameter $\theta$, the coordinates of $C$ are

$$(x,y)=\big(N\cos (\beta\pm\theta),\;\;M\sin(\pm\alpha\mp\theta)\big)$$

where $N=2, M=3$.

> **Additional Note III**

Here's a more straightforward derivation.

$$\begin{align}
r^2
&=N^2\cos^2(\beta-\theta)+M^2\sin^2(\alpha+\theta)\\
&=\tfrac12 \big(N^2(1+\cos2(\beta+\theta))+M^2(1-\cos 2(\alpha+\theta))\big)\\
&=\tfrac12 \big(N^2+M^2+N^2\cos2(\beta+\theta)-M^2\cos 2(\alpha+\theta)\big)\\
&=\tfrac 12
\big(N^2+M^2+N^2(\cos 2\beta\cos2\theta+\sin2\beta\sin2\theta)-M^2(\cos2\alpha\cos2\theta-\sin2\alpha\sin2\theta)\big)\\
&=\tfrac12 \big(N^2+M^2+\overbrace{(N^2\cos2\beta-M^2\cos2\alpha)}^A\cos2\theta+\overbrace{(N^2\sin2\beta+M^2\sin2\alpha)}^B\sin2\theta\big)\\
&=\tfrac12 \big(N^2+M^2+\sqrt{A^2+B^2}(\sin\gamma\cos2\theta+\cos\gamma\sin2\theta)\big)
\qquad\qquad\qquad\color{grey}{\big(\tan\gamma=\tfrac AB\big)}\\
&=\tfrac12 \big(N^2+M^2+\sqrt{A^2+B^2}\underbrace{\sin(\gamma+2\theta)}_
{ \substack{ \text{max: $+1$}\\ \text{min: $-1$} } } \big)\\
{r^*}^2
&=\tfrac12\big(M^2+N^2\pm\sqrt{A^2+B^2}\big)\\
{r_1^*}^2 {r_2^*}^2&=\tfrac14 \big(M^2+N^2-\sqrt{A^2+B^2}\big)\big(M^2+N^2+\sqrt{A^2+B^2}\big)\\
&=\tfrac14 \big((M^2+N^2)^2-(A^2+B^2)\big)\\
&=\tfrac14 \big((M^2+N^2)^2-2(M^2+N^2)L^2+L^4\big)
\qquad \text{(see below)}\\
&=\tfrac14 \big((L^2-M^2-N^2\big)^2\\
r_1^*r_2^*
&=\frac {L^2-M^2-N^2}2\\
\text{Area of Ellipse}=\pi r_1^*r_2^*
&=\color{red}{\pi\left(\frac {L^2-M^2-N^2}2\right)}\\
&=\color{red}{\pi\left(\frac {4^2-3^2-2^2}2\right)}\\
&=\color{red}{\tfrac32\pi}\\\\
\text{NB:}\hspace{3cm}\\
A^2+B^2
&=(N^2\cos2\beta-M^2\cos2\alpha)^2+(N^2\sin2\beta+M^2\sin2\alpha)^2\\ 
&=M^4+N^4-2M^2N^2(\cos2\alpha\cos2\beta-\sin2\alpha\sin2\beta)\\
&=M^4+N^4-2M^2N^2\cos2(\alpha+\beta)\\
&=(M^2+N^2)^2-4M^2N^2\cos^2(\alpha+\beta)\big)\\
&=\big(M^2+N^2\underbrace{-2MN\cos(\alpha+\beta)}_{M^2+N^2-L^2}\big)\cdot \big(\underbrace{M^2+N^2+2MN\cos(\alpha+\beta)}_{L^2})\big)\\
&=\big(2(M^2+N^2)-L^2\big) L^2\\
\end{align}$$

It can also be shown that the optimal $\theta (\theta^*)$ (i.e. when $C$ is at end of semi-major/minor axes) is given by 
$$\tan\theta^*=\frac{M^2-N^2\pm L\sqrt{2(M^2+N^2)-L^2}}{\sqrt{(L+M-N)(L-M+N)(-L+M+N)(L+M+N)}}=\frac {\sqrt{15}\pm 4\sqrt{6}}9$$
It is interesting to note that at these positions, the polar angle $\phi$ is the same value as $\theta$, i.e. $$\phi^*=\theta^*$$

---

> **Additional Note V (Cartesian Form)**

The parametric form for the locus of $C$ is
$$\big(N\cos(\beta-\theta),\; M\sin(\alpha+\theta)\big)$$

Eliminating parameter $\theta$ gives the Cartesian equation

$$\frac {\big(-xM\sin\alpha+yN\cos\beta\big)^2}{\big(MN\cos(\alpha+\beta)\big)^2}+\frac {\big(xM\cos\alpha-yN\sin\beta\big)^2}{\big(MN\cos(\alpha+\beta)\big)^2}=1$$
which can be transformed into the standard Cartesian form of a rotated ellipse

$$\frac{\big(x\cos\gamma+y\sin\gamma\big)^2}{P^2}+\frac {\big(x\sin\gamma-y\cos\gamma\big)^2}{Q^2}=1$$
where angle of rotation
$$\gamma=\arctan\left(\frac{M^2-N^2\pm\sqrt{(M^2+N^2)^2-(2MNcos(\alpha+\beta))^2}}{2MN\sin(\alpha+\beta)}\right)$$
and square of semimajor/minor axes

$$P^2, Q^2=\frac12\left(M^2+N^2\mp\sqrt{(M^2+N^2)^2-(2MN\cos(\alpha+\beta))^2}\right)$$

---

> **Original Answer (cont'd)**

The loci of $C, C'$ are rotated ellipses. The locus of $P$ is an ellipse.

For the loci of $C, C'$, using ideas in the solutions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3255698/rotated-ellipse-parametric-determining-semi-major-and-semi-minor-axes), it can be further shown that the semi-minor and semi-major axes occur when $r^2 (=x^2+y^2)$ is at a minimum/maximum correspondingly. This occurs when $\theta$ takes on the values $\theta^*_{min}$ and $\theta^*_{max}$ $(=\theta^*_{min} + \frac {\pi}2)$ respectively, where 
$$\tan 2\theta^*_{min}=-\dfrac {2h}{p-q}=-\tfrac 35\sqrt{15}$$
This gives 
$$\begin{align}
{r^*}^2
&=2^2\cos^2 (\beta-\theta^*)+3^2\sin^2 (\alpha+\theta^*)\\
&=2^2\cdot \tfrac12 (1+\cos2(\beta-\theta))+3^2\cdot\tfrac12 (1-\cos 2(\alpha+\theta))\\
&=\tfrac 12 \big[(2^2+3^2)\mp(p+q)\sqrt{4h^2+(p-q)^2}\big]\\
&=\tfrac 12 \big[13\mp 4\sqrt{10}\big]\\
r^*&=\sqrt{\tfrac{13\mp4\sqrt{10}}2}\\
&=2\pm \sqrt{\tfrac 52}\\
\text{Area of ellipse}\\
\text{ (region enclosed by locus of $C$)}
&=\pi \;r^*_1\; r^*_2\\
&=\pi \left(2^2-\tfrac 52 \right)\\
&=\color{red}{\tfrac 32 \pi} \qquad \blacksquare
\end{align}$$

Note that the area can also be calculated using $\pi (pq-h^2)$.

See Desmos implementation [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/eaqjizwmuc).
[image]

---

(NB: note that $p=\frac {21}8, q=\frac {11}8, h=\frac 38\sqrt{15}$, $\alpha=\arctan (h/p), \beta=\arctan(h/q)$)

Here's an interesting wikipedia entry on the [Trammel of Archimedes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trammel_of_Archimedes), an ellipsograph used for drawing ellipses.

> **Additional Note I**

It is interesting to note that, for the general case,  the area of the ellipse, i.e. area bounded by the locus of $C$, is given by 
$$\color{red}{\pi \left(\frac{L^2-M^2-N^2}2\right)}$$
 where $L=AB, M=AC, N=BC$, and the semi-minor/major axes lengths are given by
$$r^*=\frac {L\pm \sqrt{2(M^2+N^2)-L^2}}2$$

Also, if $\angle ACB$ is a right angle, i.e. $L^2=M^2+N^2$, then the area is zero, i.e. the locus is a line segment (on the line $y=x$).

---

> **Additional Note II**

This note here shows an alternative derivation.

Let $u=\alpha+\theta, v=\beta-\theta$. Hence $u+v=\alpha+\beta$.

Also, let $m_1=M\sin u,\;\; m_2=M\cos u, n_1=N\sin v,\;\; n_2=N\cos v$.

From above, we have

$$\begin{align}
r^2&=N^2 \cos^2 (\beta -\theta)+M^2 \sin^2 (\alpha+\theta)\\
\frac {dr^2}{d\theta}&=2N^2\cos(\beta-\theta)\sin(\beta-\theta)+2M^2\sin(\alpha+\theta)\cos(\alpha+\theta)\\
&=2n_1n_2+2m_1m_2\\
&=0\qquad\qquad\qquad \;\;\text{at max/min }r^2\\
n_1n_2+m_1m_2&=0\\
(n_1n_2+m_1m_2)^2&=0\\
\color{\lightgrey}{m_1^2n_1^2+m_2^2n_2^2}+n_1^2n_2^2+m_1^2m_2^2&=-2m_1m_2n_1n_2+\color{\lightgrey}{m_1^2n_1^2+m_2^2n_2^2}\\
(n_2^2+m_1^2)(n_1^2+m_2^2)&=(m_2n_2-m_1n_1)^2\\\\
\color{\lightgrey}{(n_2^2+m_1^2)^2+2(n_2^2+m_1^2)(m_2n_2-m_1n_1)}\\
+(n_2^2+m_1^2)(n_1^2+m_2^2)&=(m_2n_2-m_1n_1)^2\\
&\;\;\;\color{\lightgrey}{+(n_2^2+m_1^2)^2+2(n_2^2+m_1^2)(m_2n_2-m_1n_1)}\\\\
(\underbrace{n_2^2+m_1^2}+\underbrace{m_2n_2-m_nn_1})^2
&=\big[\underbrace{m_1^2+m_2^2}+\underbrace{n_1^2+n_2^2}+\underbrace{2(m_2n_2-m_1n_1)}\big](\underbrace{n_2^2+m_1^2})\\
\big({r^*}^2+MN\cos(u+v)\big)^2
&=\big(\underbrace{\;\;\;M^2\;\;\;\;\;+N^2+2MN\cos(u+v)}_{L^2}\big)\;\;\;\;\;{r^*}^2\\
\big({r^*}^2+\tfrac {L^2-M^2-N^2}2\big)^2
&=L^2{r^*}^2\\
{r^*}^2-L{r^*}+\underbrace{\tfrac {L^2-M^2-N^2}2}_{\text{Product of roots, }r_1 r_2}&=0\\
\text{Area of ellipse}=\pi\; r_1^* r_2^*
&=\color{red}{\pi\bigg(\frac {L^2-M^2-N^2}2\bigg)}\qquad\blacksquare
\end{align}$$

NB: 
$$\small r^*=\frac {L\pm \sqrt{L^2-2(L^2-M^2-N^2)}}2
=\frac {L\pm \sqrt{2(M^2+N^2)-L^2}}2\\$$

---

> **Additional Note IV (Area of Union of Both Ellipses)**
>   (per OP's additional question in the comments)

The union of the two ellipses (which are of equal area) is twice the area of one ellipse less the area of intersection - the near-diamond-shaped area. The area of one of four equal quadrants is given by

$$Q=\tfrac12r_1r_2\left[\tan^{-1} \big(\tfrac {r_1}{r_2}\cdot\tan\psi_2^*\big)-\big(\tfrac {r_1}{r_2}\cdot\tan\psi_1^*\big)\right]$$
where $\psi_1^*, \psi_2^*$ are the angle between the semimajor-axis in the positive quadrant and the positive $y$-axis and negative $x$-axis respectively. Since $\psi^*=\tfrac \pi 2-\phi^*=\tfrac\pi 2-\theta^*$, this is equivalent to

$$Q=\tfrac12r_1r_2\left[\tan^{-1} \big(\tfrac {r_1}{r_2}\cdot(-\tan\theta^*)\big)-\big(\tfrac {r_1}{r_2}\cdot\cot\theta^*\big)\right]$$

The area of intersection is $4Q$.If $E=$ is the area of one ellipse, the the area of the union of both ellipses is given by $2E-4Q$.

Comment: Excellent solution! How would you go about finding the area of the union of the two possible ellipses?

Comment: Thanks! :) Finding the area of intersection of the two ellipses might be more complicated.

Comment: For future reference, we have the [sandbox](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4666/sandbox-for-drafts-of-long-complex-posts) on meta for composing long and complex posts before posting them.

Comment: @AsafKaragilaThanks - that is a useful feature.

Comment: @MichaelMcGruder - See Additional Note IV re your question on area of union of two ellipses.

Answer (score 3):

You have some sort of a "do-nothing machine"

The midpoint of $AB$ traces a circle.

Lets start with $B = (0,0), A = (4,0)$  Where is $C$

Area  $= \sqrt {(\frac 92)(\frac 52)(\frac 32)(\frac 12)} = \frac {\sqrt {135}}{4}$

$h = \frac {\sqrt {135}}{8}$

And from Pythagoras theorem we get that the altitude splits the base into segments $\frac {11}{8},\frac {21}{8}$

Note there are 2 ways we can orient the triangle at this time.

$(\frac {11}{8},\frac  {\sqrt {135}}{4})\\
(\frac {11}{8},-\frac  {\sqrt {135}}{4})\\
$

Lets pick $C = (\frac {11}{8},\frac  {\sqrt {135}}{4})$ for now.

$A = (4\cos\theta, 0)\\
B = (0, 4\sin\theta)\\
C = (\frac {11}{8}\cos\theta + h\sin\theta, \frac {21}{8}\sin\theta + h\cos\theta)$

$C = (2\cos(\theta - \arctan\frac {\sqrt{135}}{11}), 3\sin (\theta + \arctan \frac{\sqrt {135}}{21}))$

That will trace out something that is roughly an ellipse.  I don't think it will be exactly an ellipse.

And swapping the different starting position of $C$ will change the sign on the angle of orientation.